# Create a mapping of elements from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, associative-array

I have two arrays which are outputs of a clustering algorithm. Is there a possibility of an automatic way to find the **associative mapping**.

Consider two label arrays:

```
array1 = [0,0,1,2,3]
array2 = [4,4,6,8,7]
```

Visually these look the same, but for a larger label set, I want to find a mapping like `{0:4,1:6,2:8,3:7}`.

Does Python have any method to do this?

I have looked at **sklearn metrics** for similar solution, no luck yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the same elements in array1 don't have the same elements in array2, what's the expected behaviour

Comment: there should still be a mapping for the extra elements in array2, if we use dict(), then the elements are skipped. is there another alternative to this problem.

Comment: yes, then you would need a list of values e,g `{0:[4,5], 1:[6,7]}` for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can create a dictionary with the key as the element of the first list and value as the element on the second list, by [zipping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together, and converting the output to a dictionary

```
array_1 = [0,0,1,2,3]
array_2 = [4,4,6,8,7]

#Zip the two lists together, and create a dictionary out of the zipped lists
mapping = dict(zip(array_1, array_2))
print(mapping)
```

The output will be

```
{0: 4, 1: 6, 2: 8, 3: 7}
```

Note that if you have duplicate elements in `array_1` but the corresponding elements in `array_2` are different, the last element of `array_2` will be picked in the mapping for the duplicate elements, e.g for `[0,0,1,1]` and `[4,5,6,7]`. the mapping will be `{0: 5, 1: 7}`, since `5` is picked for duplicate element `0` and `7` is picked for duplicate element `1`